# Warning: foreach staement

Tags: php, foreach

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if(!empty($_SESSION['cart'])){
        foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $key => $val){
            if($val==0){
                unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
            }else{
                $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['quantity']=$val;}
        }
        }
    }
```

**Error:**

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: ok, so what do you want from us?

Comment: how can i fix this warning

Comment: make sure that `$_POST['quantity']` is actually sent to the script and that it is an array.

Comment: According to Stack Overflow etiquette, if you post a question, you must ask a question. :) Regardless, if you encounter errors in your code you should do some echos or print_r statements of variables. For example, try print_r($_POST) or print_r($_POST['quantity']). The foreach loop requires an array of values, not just a simple value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have array in `$_POST['quantity']` but you have something else, do `var_dump($_POST['quantity']);` to see what inside `$_POST['quantity']`.
Also you can change `if(!empty($_SESSION['cart']))` to `if(!empty($_SESSION['cart']) && is_array($_POST['quantity']))`

Answer (score 1):

I would check and make sure that `$_POST['quantity']` is definitely an array.

`var_dump($_POST['quantity']); //This will make it pretty clear if it's an array or not`.

Without seeing the form that you are submitting we can't help much.